# iOS parsing: string is null

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing, nsstring

Here is the method in my item class which beckons my parser. This method is beckoned by my viewController.

```
- (NSString*)img
{
if (img!=nil) return img;
   if (_description!=nil)
   { 
 //    NSString* description = [NSString stringWithString:_description];
htmlParser = [[HtmlParser alloc] InitHtmlByString:_description]; 
   }
return img;
}
```

Here is my parser's init method...

```
- (HtmlParser *) InitHtmlByString:(NSString *)htmlString {

NSString *description = currentHTMLElement.description;
NSLog(@"%@", description);
NSData *nsData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)description];
elementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:nsData];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];

currentHTMLElement = [ArticleItem alloc];
                  return self;
}
```

Right now I am getting an output like this:

013-02-11 15:26:18.564 DrillDownRSS[9251:c07] (null)

2013-02-11 15:26:18.612 DrillDownRSS[9251:c07] (null)

2013-02-11 15:26:18.662 DrillDownRSS[9251:c07] (null)

2013-02-11 15:26:18.695 DrillDownRSS[9251:c07] (null)

---

Here is the solution, thanks to the below comment's thoughtful advice.

```
//    NSString *description = [NSString string];
NSData *nsData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)string];
elementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:nsData];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
NSLog(@"%@", string);

currentHTMLElement = [ArticleItem alloc];
                  return self;
```

Comment: This is probably not related, but I'm just curious why is `htmlString` passed in as a parameter but not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid any self declared variable / Property named *description*.
I had a strange bug, because this overrided the default description (which each object has.)